# imacros , java script / datasource .csv number of rows = loop value

Tags: javascript, loops, csv, imacros

---

```
date.csv  like this 

    day,month,year
    15,04,2016
    22,06,2017
    29,06,2017
    23,06,2017
```

---

Example there is 4 rows  in date.csv file.

---

```
var accounts = 7; 
for(k= 1; k<= accounts; k++){
iimDisplay("first_loop: "+ k);
var extract;
extract =  "CODE:";
extract +=  "SET !REPLAYSPEED fast" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "SET !DATASOURCE date.csv" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{CSV}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/wps/wcm/connect/tcmb+tr/tcmb+tr" + "\n";
extract +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:ARŞİV" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "FRAME F=1" + "\n"; 

extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:doviz ATTR=NAME:gun CONTENT=%{{!COL1}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:doviz ATTR=NAME:ay CONTENT=%{{!COL2}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:doviz ATTR=NAME:yil CONTENT=%{{!COL3}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=NAME:doviz ATTR=NAME:chk" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n"; 

iimSet("CSV", k);
iimPlay(extract);
}
```

accounts is a variable set 7 times,   this code work fine .. but i need  change loop value

could you tell me . how can i do to change "account" variable value  as a date.csv rows count..

regards,
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
var accounts = 7;
var extract;

extract =  "CODE:";
extract +=  "SET !REPLAYSPEED fast" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "SET !DATASOURCE date.csv" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{CSV}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/wps/wcm/connect/tcmb+tr/tcmb+tr" + "\n";
extract +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:ARŞİV" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "FRAME F=1" + "\n"; 

extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:doviz ATTR=NAME:gun CONTENT=%{{!COL1}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:doviz ATTR=NAME:ay CONTENT=%{{!COL2}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:doviz ATTR=NAME:yil CONTENT=%{{!COL3}}" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=NAME:doviz ATTR=NAME:chk" + "\n"; 
extract +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n"; 

for(k= 1; k<= accounts; k++){
iimDisplay("first_loop: "+ k);
iimSet("CSV", k);
iimPlay(extract);
}
```

The macro code should all be outside the loop, see?
Also, you don't need the `var accounts = 7;` variable set. You can initiate the loop with `for(k= 1; k<=7; k++)` directly.
One last advice, if you don't mind: don't post links of live sites here.

Edit: 
added link to iMacros forum on how to count the number of rows in a csv:
http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13610&p=40923&hilit=count+number+rows+csv#p40964

Comment: so sory , You did't understand the question...

how can i do to change  variable loop value as a date.csv **rows count**..

thank you for your advice "live site link etc"

Comment: For that you need to open your file with javascript, then count the rows. Which is a different kettle of a fish. This is a thread on the iMacros forum, answered by their tech support and it answers your question:   http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13610&p=40923&hilit=count+number+rows+csv#p40964  Try it

Comment: I have seen and read this topic before. very complicated . The questioner has not received the answer. and I could not adapt my code.